# JIRA Migration from Server to Cloud: "Error importing data: {0}"

Tags: migration, cloud, jira

I'm doing JIRA Server -> Cloud Migration and I keep getting this strange error message in the middle of the import process: **"Error importing data: {0}"**.

[image]

I've made my JIRA Server (v7.5) backup zip using:

**System > IMPORT AND EXPORT > Backup system**

I've also added my "data" folder manually to the archive so it looks like this:

```
JIRA-backup-zip-file
├── activeobjects.xml
├── entities.xml
├── data
│   ├── attachments
│   └── avatars
└── logos
```

(source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/importing-issues-776636788.html)

Finally, I've imported this backup to the JIRA Cloud using:

**System > IMPORT AND EXPORT > Restore system**

I'm still using trial versions for both JIRA Server and JIRA Cloud. Has anyone else experienced something similar? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, I tried to restore without attachments but the error remains.

EDIT

I sent a ticket to support and he told me this:

Checking the logs, the import failed due to this exception error:

```
eventtype="micros_jira*" env="prod*" "ext.jira.tenant.id"="66c2183b-e7b4-48df-a29c-9945b0ea5b05" NOT (message="*provisioning*" OR message="*product*") logger=com.atlassian.jira.bc.dataimport.CloudImportTaskRunner* OR logger=com.atlassian.jira.bc.dataimport* OR logger=com.atlassian.jira.internal.rest.ProvisioningResource* (level="WARN" OR level="ERROR")  message="Exception importing entity: org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericEntityException: while inserting: [GenericEntity:ClusteredJob][cronExpression,0 0 7/12 * * ?][jobId,com.atlassian.jira.service.JiraService:10001][jobRunnerKey,com.atlassian.jira.service.DefaultServiceManager][id,10000][schedType,C][version,428][parameters,[B@21a97660][nextRun,1507680000000] (SQL Exception while executing the following:INSERT INTO public.clusteredjob (ID, JOB_ID, JOB_RUNNER_KEY, SCHED_TYPE, INTERVAL_MILLIS, FIRST_RUN, CRON_EXPRESSION, TIME_ZONE, NEXT_RUN, VERSION, PARAMETERS) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) (ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"pk_clusteredjob\"
  Detail: Key (id)=(10000) already exists.))"
```

In order to correct this, please unzip your JIRA backup and edit the entities.xml file and change the following line:

```
<ClusteredJob id="10000"
```

To a higher unused ID such as

```
ClusteredJob id="99999"
```

Save the entites.xml file and rezip all of the files. You should then be able to import.

This is outlined in a bug here:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-67644

Comment: editing the entities.xml file:

<ClusteredJob id="10000"  ==> ClusteredJob id="99999" 

worked for me

Comment: Changing "ClusteredJob id" did the trick! :) Too bad there is no way to access error log on JIRA Cloud since "Error importing data: {0}" is not quite self-explanatory. Thanks Crisstthian!